# How can a total reputation be less than this year's reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

My next door neighbor pointed a couple anomalies out from the "reputation" section (or whatever it's called).

It doesn't bother me, but it does look weird.  Just curious, **how can a total reputation be less than a year's reputation?**  Examples (can't be a**'ed to see if there are more):

[image]

Comment: Normally that sort of thing is due to caches being out of synch, the difference is only one or two upvotes

Comment: In addition to caching - possibly bounties?  I've offered a few (since that first looks to be my score) and depending on the timing it seems like that could cause this sort of discrepancy.  Although it's not an even amount... maybe downvotes too?